# Change the colour of Stars in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I find it difficult to see the apparent difference between Starred & not-Starred icons in Nautilus because the visual variation in the icons state [on/off] is low.

I would like to change the colour or icon in some way to make this difference more obvious. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem a bit complicate to change the color, think you have to rebuild nautilus for that, but maybe there is another solution. Assuming you're using the default Yaru theme you can change the icon file with a different shape.

Ideally make a copy of the icon set because your changes might be overwritten when the theme's files are updated.

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/icons/Yaru/ /usr/share/icons/Mytheme
```

Change the NAME (second line) with your theme name (e.g Mytheme)

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/icons/Mytheme/index.theme
```

And use gnome-tweak-tools to choose your own icon set.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch "tweaks" and under "appearance" / "icons" choose your theme [image: tweaks appearance]

Download shape you want, here it's a full circle :

```
wget -P $HOME/Downloads https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg
```

Backup old icon

```
sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Mytheme/scalable/status/non-starred-symbolic.svg /usr/share/icons/Mytheme/scalable/status/non-starred-symbolic.old
```

Change with the new one

```
sudo cp $HOME/Downloads/Circle_-_black_simple.svg /usr/share/icons/Mytheme/scalable/status/non-starred-symbolic.svg
```

If you want to change the starred status it's "starred-symbolic.svg". Log out to take effect.

Comment: Thanks that's a great answer. I'll change the OFF state to be a very light grey star outline & then the normal ON state will stand out well enough.

Comment: Just a note for others, I was able to get a great result thanks to Miaouf's answer. Ultimately what I did was make a copy of /usr/share/icons/yaru/scalable/status/non-starred-symbolic.svg, open it with INKSCAPE & adjust the inner path of the STAR so that the line thickness was about half as thick. SAVE AS & choose Optimised SVG.
Rename the original non-starred-symbolic-orig.svg & drop in your new file. The difference is subtle, but when the stars are ticked it really stands out a lot more.